# How to insert JavaScript pipe in TypoScript TYPO3 code

Tags: javascript, typo3, typoscript

Is it possible to insert pipe `|` (from JavaScript code) into TypoScript? When I insert that code:

```
page.jsFooterInline {
 10 = TEXT
 10.dataWrap (
<script type="text/javascript">

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

</script>

 )
}
```

TYPO3 treat the pipe element as `wrap` and cut all of code behind the pipe.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can insert inline javascript in typoscript template this way:

```
page.jsFooterInline {

  10 = TEXT
  10.value (
       var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  )
}
```

Comment: But I need to insert whole code after the `body` tag - that is the google analitics code

Comment: You mean after the opening body tag? Use jsInline instead. Here are the complete docs for the page element: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html

JavaScript should actually go to footer so that parsing doesn't slowdown page loading and rendering.

Comment: ok, I insert the code as you said using `page.jsFooterInline` and TYPO3 cut everything after first pipe `|` - the code looks like this: `/*TS_inlineFooter*/
<script type="text/javascript">var _gaq=_gaq
// -->`

Comment: Please post your typoscript. For me it works fine. What TYPO3 Version are you using?

Comment: It works - I insert `10.dataWrap` not `10.value` - my mistake :P